# Yarn V2 (Berry) Workspaces with Peer Dependencies

Tags: yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I'm trying to switch to yarn workspaces, in V2 but keep getting an `Invalid dependency range` error for the new `workspaces:` syntax when used with `peerDependencies`

I've tried using an exact range, `workspaces:*` and carat syntax `workspaces:^` with no luck.

Is this just not supported with Yarn Workspaces? Is the problem that I'm using an alpha package with a peerDependency?

If I take out the peer dependency and only leave in the devDependency in the same package (for importing the package in testing) the same package resolves successfully

workspace package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "spaceA",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "spaceB": "workspace:*", # << Fails No Matter What
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "spaceB": "workspace:1.0.0-alpha.3" # << Works with all syntaxes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current stable release of Yarn does not support peerDependencies with the `workspaces:` protocol

However as of 2021-09-28:

Setting a static version to the current "unreleased" version updates properly when bumping versions on the other package with `yarn workspace spaceB version minor` without the workspaces protocol if you are willing to chance a network install (zero if not yet released)

The current master branch and canary release both support peer dependencies

`yarn set version from sources`

Or

`yarn set version canary`

When these versions have been released to stable this issue should be resolved